# ReferenceError: React is not defined (React Navigation / Bottom Tabs Navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

following [this tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator)  I am trying out the bottom Tab Navigator
But for some reason I get the error "ReferenceError: React is not defined"
Here is my code

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import TestScreen from '../App/Screens/Test';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function Tabs(){
return (  
<Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Test" component={TestScreen}/>
</Tab.Navigator>
);
}

export default Tabs;
```

I hope someone has a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to import React from 'react'

`import React from 'react';`